# Calling a method of a react class in a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing Login Authentication in my reactjs aplication following the  tutorial https://auth0.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-your-react-flux-app//

I have written a class call the AuthService and inside the AuthService I have a function call Login as shown below

```
import LoginActions from './LoginAction';
const URL_LOGIN = 'loginurl';
class AuthService {
   login(username, password) {
     // do something
  }
}
```

Now, I am calling this Login method in my Login Component as shown below

```
//this function is to save data to the API
loginUser = (user) => {
  // Here, we call an external AuthService.
    Auth.login(user.username, user.password)
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Error logging in", err);
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Everythin works well but when I submit data, I get the error

TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__authentication_AuthService**.a.login(...) is undefined

When I console log at the login method of the AuthService class, I see the returned data. I have looked around for a fast solution to this error but I have not gotten it. Any help on this will be appreciate.
I do not want to bring this action to the component as I am also going to use it in other areas of my application.

Also,I am a newbie to Reactjs as this is my first Authentication I am doing here.

Comment: You’ve defined login as an instance method, but are calling it like a static method. Either add the static keyword before the function name, or create an instance of Auth before calling login on it.

Comment: It's unclear from the question why you need a class. It doesn't maintain a state. Possibly it isn't needed at all.

Comment: @djfdev provide as an answer.

Comment: djfdev thats but adding static to the function does not change anything

Comment: estus , I do not really know, but I followed the example on the tutorial provided in the question. But when I remove it from the class, it gives syntax error which is understandable

Comment: djfdev I create the instance as you rightly said by importing the class  as this  import Auth from '../_authentication/AuthService';

Answer (score 0):

Add the `static` keyword before the login method in the AuthService class.

Comment: Oreoluwa, It doesnt work by adding static. when I add static, it gives me exactly the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was waiting for [djfdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3213172/djfdev) to see an answer as in his comment:

> You’ve defined login as an instance method, but are calling it like a static method. Either add the static keyword before the function name, or create an instance of Auth before calling login on it.

But it seems he's not providing an answer. What he meant that you can define a static method like:

```
static login(username, password) {
```

Or call login method in an instance like:

```
const auth = new Auth
auth.login(user.username, user.password)
```

Further, I hope you're exporting the class like:

```
export default AuthService
```

And importing it like:

```
import Auth from '...'
```

Comment: Yes I am exporting and Importing

Answer (score 0):

From my comment on the OP:

> You’ve defined login as an instance method, but are calling it like a static method. Either add the static keyword before the function name, or create an instance of Auth before calling login on it.

So your two options are to, A) use the `static` keyword to define your method on the class itself:

```
import LoginActions from './LoginAction';
const URL_LOGIN = 'loginurl';
class AuthService {
   static login(username, password) {
     // do something
  }
}
```

Or B) create an instance of `Auth` before calling the login method:

```
loginUser = (user) => {
  // Here, we call an external AuthService.
  new AuthService().login(user.username, user.password)
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Error logging in", err);
      console.log(err);
  });
```

See the MDN docs for [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried both methods and they do not work. I have added static as proposed but it does not work. I have also called  login method as an instance but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding static to the login method as advice above and removing the catch from it.